# React setState() not rendering before callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display an overlay while requesting new data from the server. I'm using a setState callback, but the overlay never seems to render.

Here's the overlay component:

```
export default class Overlay extends React.Component {

  render () {

    // This always prints out as expected
    console.log('overlay props', this.props)

    var overlayStyle = {///}
    return this.props.show ? (<div style={overlayStyle} id="PROBLEMCHILD"></div>) : null;
  }
}
```

And here's the main App component:

```
export default class AppView extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      ///
      isLoading: false,
    }
  }

  changeDay (dayTs) {
    ////
    // HERE'S THE THING. Triggered by a button elsewhere.
    ////
    this.setState({isLoading: true}, () => {
      var bodyElem = document.getElementById('body')
      ReactDOM.render(<AppView day={dayTs} />, bodyElem)
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
            <div id="outer-container">
                {titleBar}
                {footerBar}         
            </div>
            <Overlay show={this.state.isLoading} />
    )
  }
}
```

A calendar button component is clicked to trigger AppView.changeDay(). When I comment out the callback for changeDay, the overlay shows up immediately. When I re enable it, the Overlay state does change (console.log immediately tells me that props.show is TRUE), but the overlay doesn't show, even when I have the ajax server sleep for 4 seconds.

Is this somehow related to re-render of the root AppView element in changeDay()? From what I've read, re-rendering the root component to pass it new props just makes it update itself.

**Update:** Using Chrome inspector, I can see that the element IS being added. It just doesn't draw to the screen for some reason.

Comment: You're rendering right after you set state. I have no idea what you're trying to do... why are you rendering the component itself inside the component's code...?

Comment: I'm also confused as to what you're trying to accomplish with that callback. Why would you use `ReactDOM.render()` inside an already rendered component?

Comment: React re-renders the component every time you call setState. That callback could be causing problems. It seems you could solve this just by putting `dayTs` on `AppView`'s state

Comment: @KyleRichardson From what I've read, that's the way to hand new props to a root element. As long as it's attached to the same html element, this just forces an update. (I tried logging in the AppView constructor, and the constructor only gets called on page load.)

Comment: Try to include `this.changeDay = this.changeDay.bind(this);` in the bottom of AppView constructor method. Tell me if it works out so I can elaborate a proper answer

Comment: the exact code you have posted wouldn't even compile. your AppView render method can't return adjacent elements like that. also you should definitely not be selecting stuff and calling ReactDOM render inside a component, that's wildly non-sensical

Comment: @azium The exact code I posted has been watered down for clarity. The full version compiles fine. Concerning the re-render of itself, I've seen this done many times, and I know I've seen this technique mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I think you're getting confused. it makes sense to call reactDOM render multiple times **outside** of the react context, never inside

Comment: @azium Passing new props to the root. It works, and as far as I know, it's the only way it works. (Yes, I know converting props->state would be more idiomatic, but this works.)

Comment: you're already using state....

Comment: @azium Not for "days" and a few others that come from the server. A lot of the window dressing (including Overlay triggers) are in state.

Comment: I don't see anything else in the code you posted that would cause such behaviour. I would try moving whatever it is you need into state and not calling reactDOM render multiple times and see

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
 this.setState({
     ...
 }, ()=>{
     this.forceUpdate(()=>{
         ...
     })
 })
```

Not sure how kosher this is